# Yeoman install component fails

Tags: yeoman, bower

When I execute `yeoman install git://github.com/paperjs/paper.js.git`, it fails. This is the output:

> Running "bower:install:git://github.com/paperjs/paper.js.git" (bower)
>
> task bower cloning git://github.com/paperjs/paper.js.git bower caching
>
> git://github.com/paperjs/paper.js.git bower fetching paper.js bower
>
> checking out paper.js#39f744de0c117e678b7c663dbf489c55def6f415 bower
>
> copying
>
> /Users/my-username/.bower/paper.js/58f9c1c5f33cae79df922c8fde57158c
>
> GET https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/canvas `<FATAL>` canvas not
>   found `</FATAL>`

Seems like it is looking for a 'canvas'-module which doesn't exists. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

It probably has to do with 'cavas' being defined as a dependency in `package.json`, but the `package.json` file is meant for [NPM](https://npmjs.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It probably has to do with 'cavas' being defined as a dependency in package.json, but the package.json file is meant for NPM.

That's correct. It's an invalid component since it's missing a component.json file, which is required if a component has dependencies. You can ask the author of Paper.js to add a component.json file, or fork the repo and add it yourself.

In addition their git tags, which `yeoman install` (Bower) uses, are invalid [semver](http://semver.org) (`v0.22` while the valid notation is `0.2.2`). This will cause it to not work.